# Adobe Target Opt-Out link will not work if overrideMboxEdgeServer is true

Tags: javascript, adobe, target, at.js

Since at.js version [1.6.2](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/target/using/implement-target/client-side/target-atjs-versions.html#section_88BE2F69943D4280B8170F377886B58E), [overrideMboxEdgeServer](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/target/using/implement-target/client-side/functions-overview/targetgobalsettings.html#section_42C759AE9B524A43B8659018677224B8) is set to true by default. This ensures that the request URL is no longer *clientCode*.tt.omtrdc.net but mboxedge *clusterNumber* .tt.omtrdc.net. The Edge Network ensures timely data delivery. I would also like to use this advantage. My problem that the Pricacy Opt-Out Link solution does not work anymore. The user can prevent all countings and content delivery via a [link](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/target/using/implement-target/before-implement/privacy/privacy.html#section_E7A62B7B99C94B3A806CB262D16E27FC). The link builds like this:

```js
<a href="https://clientcode.tt.omtrdc.net/optout"> Your Opt Out Language Here </a>
```

This does not work in combination with overrideMboxEdgeServer = true. Also, I do not want to use the current cluster as the Opt-Out-Link, if that works - because that affects other domains or customers. 
Does anyone have the same problem or know a solution to the problem? 
I'm going to have to write my own Opt-Out solution, but has Adobe just forgotten or been thinking about it, or did I miss something?

Current used at.js version: **1.7.1**